# Performance issue when using Authentication type for ConnectionStrings as Active Directory Managed Identity

Tags: c#, authentication, azure-sql-database, connection-string, azure-managed-identity

The current project is using azure functions published on azure.
When we compare the connection performance to Azure-SQL-Database between two ConnectionString Option Types:

1. Standard type

Server=tcp:myserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Persist Security Info=False;UserID=mylogin@myserver;Password=myPassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;

2. Azure AD identity type

Server=tcp:myserver.database.windows.net; Authentication=Active Directory Managed Identity; Database=myDataBase; Column Encryption Setting=enabled

In some cases, the connection time to the database in the second type takes about more than 10 seconds. While the first type only takes a maximum of 2 seconds at the same time.

Is this related to the Azure AD identity token taking longer to access?

I want to clarify the reason why the connection to the DB is slow.

-> Below is the code that I suspect

```
        // Initialize AzureKeyVault provider
        SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider azureKeyVaultProvider = new(new DefaultAzureCredential());

        // Register AzureKeyVault provider
        SqlConnection.RegisterColumnEncryptionKeyStoreProviders(
            customProviders: new Dictionary<string, SqlColumnEncryptionKeyStoreProvider>(
                capacity: 1, comparer: StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            {
                { SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider.ProviderName, azureKeyVaultProvider}
            });
```

Comment: Every X hours when the access_token is refreshed, it will take a little more time. Also in your example the connection are not equivalent. For the second connectionstring you have `Column Encryption` enabled.

Comment: I tried removing Column Encryption Setting=enabled but the connection time to the DB still doesn't change.
As you said, access_token refresh will take a lot of time, but taking 10 seconds is hardly acceptable. Is there any way to fix them?

Comment: is it on the deployed app or locally ?

Comment: not locally, it has been deployed on azure function

Comment: is it dotnet ? which function runtime ?

Comment: yes it is dotnet 6.0, and is run on AzureFunction